# C# Conversion Error Help

Tags: c#, inheritance, object

I am getting this error.

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ModelBase.IModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ModelBase.User>'
```

User inherits IModel, but I am not casting correctly.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
List<User> users = (List<User>)this.GetAll();
// GetAll() return type is List<IModel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<User> users = this.GetAll().Cast<User>().ToList();
```